# Showing the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^2}{x^3+n^3}$ is uniformly convergent on $[0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series, uniform-convergence

> **Exercise** Show that the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^2}{x^3+n^3}$ is uniformly convergent on $[0,\infty)$.

More precisely we define $f_n(x) : = \frac{x^2}{x^3+n^3}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and we we seek to show that there exists some function $f(x)$ such that the sequence of functions $\langle f_n \rangle$ converge to $f$ uniformly on $[0,\infty)$.

Any hints or tips on how to approach this? It is a well known fact that power series

$$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k(x-c)^k$$

converge uniformly and absolutely on their interval of convergence $(c-R,c+R)$. Any advice?

Comment: Directly, try the usual Weierstrass $M$-test approach to prove uniform convergence. Writing the series as $\sum f_n$, you find that the maximum value of $f_n$ (at $x=\root3\of 2 n$) is $M_n=\frac{2^{2/3}}{3n}$, and $\sum M_n$ diverges. This alone does not prove that the series fails to converge uniformly, but it certainly suggests that it cannot. Now you need an approach such as Mindlack provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems false: let $R_n(x)=\sum_{p > n}{\frac{x^2}{x^3+p^3}}$. Then
$$
R_n(n) \geq \sum_{p=n+1}^{2n}{\frac{n^2}{n^3+p^3}} \geq \sum_{p=n+1}^{2n}{\frac{n^2}{9n^3}} \geq 0.1
$$
So $R_n$ cannot converge uniformly to zero.

Comment: I think you are right. This cannot be uniformly convergent. Well, M-test is not a necessary condition but still.....in these types of problems usually M-test gives you what we need.

Comment: Do you mean $R_n(x)=\sum_{p>n}\frac{x^2}{x^3+p^3}$ instead of summing something independent of $p$?

Comment: @user10354138: yes, thank you. I corrected.

Comment: @Daniel Schepler: in this case, $n$ is a constant and it’s intended: the sum is $1/9$. I’m using the fact that $n^3+p^3 \leq n^3+8n^3=9n^3$ and $p^2 \geq n^2$.